# Error when trying to use jQuery UIDialog with prototype.js loaded?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I am trying to use jQuery UIDialog in a JSP page which has prototype.js loaded. The Code gets executed but instead of dialog I get text on the page. When the prototype is commented UI Dialog pops up. I am already using jQuery.noConflict(); to revert control of $ back to prototype.

```
Error : Uncaught TypeError: Object function (object) {
return Object.extend.apply(this, [this, object]);
} has no method 'push'                                  in jQuery-1.8.3.js: 2743
```

Comment: <script src="javascript/prototype.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
    <script>
    function firstWarning(){
    jQuery('#dialog').attr('title', 'Timeout').text('sessionTimeout').dialog({buttons: {     
    'Ok' : function(){ jQuery(this).dialog('close'); } }, closeOnEscape: true, draggable:    
    false, resizable: false, position: 'center', modal: true } );}

    jQuery(window).load(function(){  
    setTimeout(firstWarning,2000);});
    </script>

Comment: Exact code I am using ...Has anyone seen this issue before ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use prototype.js and jQuery you have to load first jQuery then prototype.js, or if first is prototype.js add in first line of jQuery.noConflict().

Without it prototype reserve most function that got identical selectors etc from jQuery.